# what is the maximum value of $x(x+y)^3$ given that $x^2+y^2/d=1$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Without losing generality, we can assume $x,y\geq 0$ and then use $x$ to replace $y$. This is complicated.

Instead I use $x=\sin\theta$, $y=\sqrt{d}\cos\theta$, and then I only need to  get the maximum value of $\sin\theta(\sin\theta+\sqrt{d}\cos\theta)^3$, but this is still complicated, and I can not get the answer so far.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: As a systematic method for constrained optimization, you can use Lagrange multiplier, then looking for optimality conditions.  Or just use the celebrated [KKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions.

Comment: Thanks, but Lagrange multiplier is the same as what I said in the first sentence.

Comment: I did this in Mathematica and the result is nasty looking!

Comment: @Moo could you please show me the result, or is the result= $o((d+1)^{3/2})$?

Comment: The max is $\frac{1}{16} \left(9 d+\sqrt{(3 d+4)^3}+8\right)$. The $(x, y)$ are ugly looking. For $d = 5$, we get max $=8.48869$ at $(x, y) = ( 0.687959,1.62283)$.

Comment: @Moo. I (at least, a CAS I used) agree with your comments and result but provided that $d>0$. The $x,y$ seem to be monsters !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Agreed, I should have mentioned that I assumed $d$ was positive and real in my calculations. Indeed, the $(x,y)$ result is ugly.

Comment: For negative d it seems you get an hyperbola structure that does not intersect with the other surface.

Comment: @Moo BTW, could you please also show the value of x and y that to get the maximum value?

Comment: @olivia: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+x+%28x+%2B+y%29%5E3+subject+to+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2%2Fd+%3D+1%2C+d%3E+0

Answer (score 0):

Thought this pictorial view for d=2 and d=3 might provide some indight

[image]